# PHP: Can I store a function in a class object and pass values to it for the function to interpret. Python can do it, but can PHP?

Tags: python, php, class

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to implement code similar to the following Python code:

```
class _Mapper(object):
    # Holds the name of the function to call when we want to predict a value.
    # There may be dozens of these _Mapper objects stored in an array which are
    # created by calling _create_couplet() in a nested loop
    def __init__(self, estimator):
        self.estimator = estimator

def _create_couplet(pairings, A, B):
    # Gets the data for the pairing from the pairings class and returns a Mapper
    # object containing the function (either function 1 or function2 - defined in
    # pairing class) that we'll use to to predict the value
    if A < B:
        return (_Mapper(pairings.function1))
    else:
        return (_Mapper(pairings.function2))

# Use the function (either function1 or function2) stored in _Mapper.estimator
# (created by _create_couplet) to estimate the new value based on the old value
newValue = _Mapper.estimator(oldValue)
```

Essentially it creates an array of _Mapper objects and each object contains a reference to a function (either function1 or function2) which is later used to calculate a value.  The crucial steps seems to be:

```
newValue = _Mapper.estimator(oldValue)
```

which takes the function held in _Mapper.estimator and then passes oldValue to as if it was newValue = function1(oldValue) or newValue = function2(oldValue)

I'm trying to implement something similar in PHP but I seem to get some kind of infinite loop when running this in the CLI.  It appears that the function name is not stored in the

```
class Pairings {
    // Define the two functions (these are just placeholders)
    public function function1($value = null) {
        return $value * 2;
    }

    public function function2($value = null) {
        return $value * 4;
    }
}

class _Mapper {
    function __construct($estimator) {
        // This should store the function that we are going to
        // use based on the value of A & B in _create_couplet()
        $this->estimator = $estimator;
    }

    function estimator($value) {
        // This should pass the value specified to either function1()
        // or function function2() and should return the result.  It
        // doesn't !
        return $this->estimator($value);
    }
}

function _create_couplet($pairing, $A, $B) {
    // Based on the value of A or B store the appropriate function
    if ($A < $B) {
        return (new _Mapper($pairing->function1()));
    } else {
        return (new _Mapper($pairing->function2()));
    }
}

// Set up some values
$oldValue = 10;
$A = 10;
$B = 5;

// Define the pairing
$pairing = new Pairings;

// Create the _Mapper object
$couplet = _create_couplet($pairing, $A, $B);

// Pass oldValue into the appropriate function and get the result back
$newValue = $couplet->estimator($oldValue);
echo ("New value: $newValue");
```

I'm sure that I've made a simple mistake but I can't see what I've missed.  How can I store a function name in an object and then pass a parameter into it so that the stored function uses that parameter and returns a value ?

Comment: `$pairing->function1()` this executes the method... `$pairing->function1` this refers to the method... in PHP you'd have to have a "Callable"... this can also be an string (for functions) or an array (for class methods) like this: `[$pairing, 'function1']`. edit: you'd have to call it with `call_user_func` or similar

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Where would the call_user_func go ?  In the Pairings class ?

Comment: No, in the Mapper, when the Pairing is accessed (estimator method)... Mapper doesn't need to know Pairing class at all, it's sufficient to have a "Callable". See the comment below, @Kern explains it pretty well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues :

in your `_create_couplet` method, the argument you're giving to `new _Mapper()` is not the function to execute, but the function result. You're executing `$pairing->function1()` and it performs `null * 2` because you're allowing `null` values, otherwise it should have failed because you're calling `function1` without argument.

As Lars suggested you should use a callable argument :

```php
//before
new _Mapper($pairing->function1());

//after
new _Mapper([$pairing, 'function1']);
```

THe second issue which provokes the infinite loop is that you try to call this callable in the `estimator` method, which is calling `$this->estimator()`. You may think that `$this->estimator()` refers to your callable contained in `$this->estimator`, but as you have a method with the same name, PHP will think you're calling the method and not the property.

THe simplest way to fix it is to name either the method or the property differently.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I've made the changes that you suggest:

        function __construct($estimator) {
            $this->estimator = call_user_func($estimator);
        }
        function getEstimate($value) {
            return $this->estimator($value);
        }

and amended:

    return (new _Mapper([$pairing, 'function1']));
    return (new _Mapper([$pairing, 'function2']));

now called by:

    $newValue = $couplet->getEstimate($oldValue);

but it gives "Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method _Mapper::estimator()" here: return $this->estimator($value)

Comment: Yes, the call_user_func() mustn't be in the constructor, because you execute the callable here if you write that. You want to execute it in the ``getEstimate`` method, you should have ``function getEstimate() { return call_user_func($this->estimator); }`` and just ``__construct($estimator) { $this->estimator = $estimator; }``

Comment: Thanks.  Despite making those changes I still get the same error: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method _Mapper::estimator() in the return call_user_func($this->estimator($value)) line. It's as if $this->estimator from the _construct() isn't being stored

Comment: ``call_user_func($this->estimator);``, if you write ``$this->estimator($value)``, PHP tries to call the method ``estimator`` of the ``_Mapper`` object, which does not exists ! ``$this->estimator`` on the other hand is the property containing your callable.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  And adding $value as the second parameter allows me to pass that into the function :-)  Thanks very much for your help and patience !